# IF NOT ISBLANK - syntax issue

Tags: excel-2016

```
 =IF(NOT(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(Table1[Company Name],Billing_Info[#All],5,FALSE) & ", " &VLOOKUP(Table1[Company Name],Billing_Info[#All],6,FALSE) & "  " &VLOOKUP(Table1[Company Name],Billing_Info[#All],7,FALSE),""))
```

What am I doing wrong - get wrong number of arguments? Trying to eliminate the comma if there is no data.

Comment: That looks unbalanced: `=IF(NOT(...)`

Comment: what would be the correct syntax to hide the comma if the returns results is blank?